# Looping over contents of a JSON without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a JSON array(?) of pairs of every state and a value associated with that state, it looks like the following below:

```
var states = [{"STATE":"AL","AMOUNT":"6"}, {"STATE":"AK","AMOUNT":"3"}]
```

I need the page to shuffle through them without reloading the page

"AL    6" [wait x seconds] then "AK    3" [wait x seconds] then etc...

I need this to run continuously.

I never use any of these languages but was told that they were my best bet.

Could someone give me some guidance on this please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to display one of the pairs each x seconds?

Comment: If that array is simply created on your page and not retrieved through AJAX or some other means, it is simply a javascript array.  No JSON involved.

Comment: It's *always* a JavaScript array. JSON is just a means of representing such an array as text to transfer it.

Comment: Technically a Javascript array *is* JSON.

Comment: No it's not. A JavaScript array is a real array in memory, whereas JSON is just a string of characters *representing* an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jsfiddle with setInterval execting a function that alternates between each state and displays it in a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/WD5Qj/1/

```
var states = '[{"STATE":"AL","AMOUNT":"6"}, {"STATE":"AK","AMOUNT":"3"}]';

json = jQuery.parseJSON(states);



var i = 0;

var cycle = function(){
  $("#state").html(json[i].STATE + json[i].AMOUNT); 
  i = (i+1)%json.length;
}

var loop = setInterval(cycle, 500);
```

Comment: It is a good idea to include the code (or important parts of it) in the answer. 1) The link can stop working 2) Users don't have to go to jsfiddle.net to see the code.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, you'd need a function that does the rotation through the array, and a variable for keeping the current state (in both meanings of the word):

```
var stateIndex = 0;

function rotate() {
    stateIndex++;

    if(stateIndex >= states.length)
        stateIndex = 0;

    displayState(states[stateIndex]);
}
```

And you'd need an interval to perform the rotation:

```
var stateRotation = window.setInterval(rotate, 3000); // 3000ms = 3 sec
```

The `stateRotation` variable is an identifier of your interval. You may  use that if you ever want to stop: `window.clearInterval(stateRotation);`

Now, the above code anticipates a function `displayState` which takes a state object and displays it. How that would look depends entirely on how you want your state to displayed. In its simplest form, something like this:

```
function displayState(state) {
    $('#state-name').html(state.STATE);
    $('#state-amount').html(state.AMOUNT);
}
```

As per your description, it might perhaps be something more like

```
$('#state-text').html(state.STATE + ' ' + state.AMOUNT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var states = [{"STATE":"AL","AMOUNT":"6"}, {"STATE":"AK","AMOUNT":"3"}]; 
var i = 0; 
setInterval(function(){ 
  var array_index = i % states.length; 
  $('#state').html( states[ array_index ]['STATE'] );
  $('#state').html( states[ array_index ]['AMOUNT'] );
  i++; 
}, 2000);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/CMwbH/).

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayNextItem(index){
    if (index === states.length) 
         displayNextItem(0);

    $("#someDiv").text(states[index]["STATE"] + " " + states[index]["AMOUNT"]);
    setTimeout(function() { displayNextItem(index + 1); }, 1000);
}
```

And then

```
displayNextItem(0);
```

Comment: I think you mean `setInterval()`, the OP wants to it repeat continuously.

Comment: @Terry: Adam is setting the timeout *inside* `displayNextItem` in which case timeout would make more sense.

Comment: @Terry - it starts over at zero when it gets to the end of the array, but setInterval may have been cleaner

Comment: @TerryR: A recursive `setTimeout` acts as an interval.

Comment: Wow 3 @ comments in a refresh! lol.  Sorry I didn't even notice the recursion, that's what I get for commenting pre-coffee.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0, l = states.length, timer, intervalLength = 5000;
timer = setInterval(function(){
  if(i >= l){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }else{
    alert(states[i++].STATE);
  }
},intervalLength);
```

Comment: If you need to start over when all items are used, replace clearInterval(timer) with i = 0;

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is waiting the `AMOUNT` number of seconds. If you want constant number of seconds then other answers are better :).

**JavaScript:**

```
var states = [{"STATE":"AL","AMOUNT":"6"}, {"STATE":"AK","AMOUNT":"3"}];

function iterate(index) {
  var time = states[index].AMOUNT;

  // replace the text with new one
  $("#output").text(states[index].STATE + " " + time);

  setTimeout(function() {
    var next = (index + 1) % states.length;
    iterate(next);
  }, time * 1000);
}

iterate(0);
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/ugumoq/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.